# UPLOAD TO AWS S3

Tags: upload, centos, filenotfoundexception

When I create a file in centos using java,
File file= new File("file.txt"),
it creates a directory with the name file.txt. When I manually created a file in the directory so that atleast it overwrites the existing file and identifies it as a file, it is not able to overwrite.It says file already exits as a result of which it stops writing into the file.

Comment: Can you share your code that creates the temp file?

Comment: Sorry, but your question is unclear. Please Edit your question to explain what you are trying to do (with code, if possible), and the exact error you are receiving. When uploading a file to Amazon S3, it does not matter if the object already exists. It will simply be overwritten.